# Re-write ShowCollums formula on PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I have an app based on MS PowerApps connected on a PowerAutomate flow.

My question is: how can re-write this code by showing more than 2 collections using (or not) the formula ShowColumns?

I have to show a collection named "collection_output" and "colletion_form".

TKS!

What I want to include in the main code:

```
ShowColumns(collection_output,"ID_SUB_FORM","LOC_SITE")),
```

Main code:

```
Set(
    var_FileLink,
    'ExporttoExcel-Version2'.Run(
        JSON(
            ShowColumns(
                collection_form,
                "FORM_QUESTION_ID",
                "FORM_QUESTION",
                "ANSWER_RADIO",
                "ANSWER_TEXT"
            ),
            IncludeBinaryData
        )
    ).filelink
);
```

Comment: If I understand your question correct, you want for your flow `ExporttoExcel-Version2` one more collection `collection_output` as Input parameter?

Comment: yes, it's exactly what I need!!

Comment: first you will have to add parameter `collection_output`  just like `collection_form` into you Power Automate and save it. Then you would have to reload you power apps, may be you will have to remove and add power automate into power apps and then you can see your new parameter. let me know if this helps.

Comment: Could you join your 2 collections together then run the flow? Or do you need to keep the collection data separate?

Answer (score 0):

Combine your two collections into one. Then pass the new joined collection to the flow.

```
ClearCollect(collection_formAndOutput, collection_form, collection_output);
Set(
    var_FileLink,
    'ExporttoExcel-Version2'.Run(
        JSON(
            ShowColumns(
                collection_formAndOutput,
                "FORM_QUESTION_ID",
                "FORM_QUESTION",
                "ANSWER_RADIO",
                "ANSWER_TEXT",
                "ID_SUB_FORM",
                "LOC_SITE"
            ),
            IncludeBinaryData
        )
    ).filelink
);
```